# MVC View Model Organization

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm new to MVC and I'm trying to understand how to organize my ModelViews. The first problem is Drop Down data. I have an Equipment Model and an EquipmentViewModel that looks like this:

```
public class EquipmentViewModel
{
    public Equipment Equipment { get; private set; }
    public SelectList EquipmentCategories { get; private set; }
    private MyEntities db = new MyEntities();

    public EquipmentViewModel(Equipment equipment)
    {
        Equipment = equipment;
        EquipmentCategories = new SelectList(db.EquipmentCategories.Where(c => c.IsActive),
                                                      "EquipmentCategoryID", "Description");
    }
```

Please note the SelectList for my category dropdown. This is all well and good. However I have another Model called Inventory. Inventory has an EquipmentID property (corresponding to a piece of equipment you see). For the creation of an inventory item it would be useful to have a drop down for the equipment category. I already have this select list in my EquipmentViewModel and it feels wrong some how to duplicate that code for the InventoryViewModel.

I have considered something like this:

```
public class InventoryViewModel
{
    MyEntities db = new MyEntities();

    public Inventory Inventory { get; set; }
    public EquipmentViewModel EquipmentViewModel { get; set; }

}
```

This seems okay to me except I am going to have an Index page for the InventoryViewModel. Basically I would be returning a List of InventoryViewModels which each has an EquipmentViewModel where in each of those has the exact same list of categories. This, too, feels wrong and I think I am misunderstanding some crucial piece of the MVC puzzle.

It also leads me to my second question: How would I return such a monstrosity from the controller? I imagine it looking something like this:

```
var list = db.Inventories
           .Select(i => new InventoryViewModel
           {
               Inventory = i,
               EquipmentViewModel = new EquipmentViewModel(i.EquipmentID)
           });
```

Which means that I'd basically be making separate trips to the database (inside the EquipmentViewModel constructor) for each EquipmentID rather than being able to join on the id. For example if I just needed the description I could do this:

```
var list = from i in db.Inventories
                   join e in db.Equipments
                   on i.EquipmentID equals e.EquipmentID
                   select new InventoryViewModel
                   {
                       Inventory = i,
                       EquipmentName = e.Description
                   };
```

Which I believe would have much better performance.  I greatly appreciate any wisdom that anyone could offer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have and idea for you,

there is no point of ducplicating your views if they are doing same thing. however if they are not doing exactly the same is better to exted or create new view than have one big one that is shared for all parts.

You can have model such as this

```
public class InventoryViewModel{


// contains all categories for every inventory
public  SelectListItem EquipmentSelect {get;set;}  

//this will contain all the items you want to assign
public List<Inventories> ListOfInventories{get;set;}
}
```

after in view you can create partial view for every item with the select list item in to it